# In Zen Koi, is it totally random which goody a blooming flower or is there some kind of determinism?

Tags: zen-koi

In the mobile game [Zen Koi](http://zenkoigame.com/), certain ‘flowers’ ‘bloom’ when you come close to them and sometimes give you either a speed power-up, or a gem to enlargen your pond or a pearl. I’ve noticed that they stay open for a given time but if you come back to them later they may have re-closed.

So far, mainly due to my poor memory and sense of pond direction, I have been unable to determine whether any kind of pattern exists. Is it known or are there any hints in the game’s code (assuming it has been analysed) as to:

- whether a specific blooming flower drops an item (can they all or only some)?
- which item a specific flower may drop (any or only certain ones)?
- if there is any other type of pattern for gem/pearl/power-up drops of flowers?
- or whether the entire thing is just based on RNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this, I have put a lot more hours into the game. I can comfortably say that these flowers (which are apparently lotuses, according to other sites) give random items.

Furthermore, my data suggests that the game decides when it wants to give you another power-up (something on the order of every two minutes) and *any* flower could be the one giving it to you — whichever you open next will be the chosen one.

Finally, although this is also still speculative, it seems as though if you move away from an item, a different flower at your destination will then produce the same item for you so you don’t miss out.